# Samba SMB daemon not starting when using apt

Tags: apt, 18.04, samba, smb

On Ubuntu 18.04 whenever I do `apt upgrade` (even if no packages to upgrade):

```
root@JohnPC:/home/john# apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up samba (2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.2)
```

...

```
Samba is not being run as an AD Domain Controller.
Please ignore the following error about deb-systemd-helper not finding samba-ad-dc.service.
Job for smbd.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status smbd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript smbd, action "restart" failed.
● smbd.service - Samba SMB Daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/smbd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2018-08-17 08:13:54 BST; 27ms ago
     Docs: man:smbd(8)
           man:samba(7)
           man:smb.conf(5)
  Process: 28404 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/smbd --foreground --no-process-group $SMBDOPTIONS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 28404 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Aug 17 08:13:54 JohnPC systemd[1]: Starting Samba SMB Daemon...
Aug 17 08:13:54 JohnPC systemd[1]: smbd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug 17 08:13:54 JohnPC systemd[1]: smbd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 17 08:13:54 JohnPC systemd[1]: Failed to start Samba SMB Daemon.
dpkg: error processing package samba (--configure):
 installed samba package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 samba
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
root@JohnPC:/home/john# systemctl status smbd.service
● smbd.service - Samba SMB Daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/smbd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2018-08-17 08:13:54 BST; 43s ago
     Docs: man:smbd(8)
           man:samba(7)
           man:smb.conf(5)
  Process: 28404 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/smbd --foreground --no-process-group $SMBDOPTIONS (code=exited, st
 Main PID: 28404 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Aug 17 08:13:54 JohnPC systemd[1]: Starting Samba SMB Daemon...
Aug 17 08:13:54 JohnPC systemd[1]: smbd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug 17 08:13:54 JohnPC systemd[1]: smbd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 17 08:13:54 JohnPC systemd[1]: Failed to start Samba SMB Daemon.
```

Comment: anything of note in /var/log/syslog ?

Comment: Could  you please [edit] your question to include the output of `sudo journalctl -lxeu smbd.service`? Thanks.

Comment: Can't show all of journalct command as too long for Comment.
john@JohnPC:~$ sudo journalctl -lxeu smbd.service
[sudo] password for john: 
-- Subject: Unit smbd.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit smbd.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is RESULT.

Comment: /var/log/syslog only has entries for kernel's UFW rejections e.g.
Aug 17 00:06:49 JohnPC kernel: [138367.824026] [UFW AUDIT] IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=b8:ae:ed:7a:6e:24:b0:7f:b9:14:cb:88:08:00 SRC=162.125.18.133 DST=192.168.101.12 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=52 ID=49907 PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=50190 WINDOW=360 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0

Answer (score 3):

Open a terminal and run the following command:

```
testparm -s
```

Do you get the following error:

```
WARNING: Ignoring invalid value 'share' for parameter 'security'
Error loading services.
```

If you do edit /etc/samba/smb.conf, find the line "security = share", and delete it. Then rerun systemctl status smbd.service.

It could be another parameter that is the culprit but that is the most common. In all cases testparm should give you a hint to the offending parameter and end with the "Error loading services" error.

**EDIT**: If you have no smb.conf at /etc/samba but have one at /usr/share/samba then copy that one to the standard location:

```
sudo cp /usr/share/samba/smb.conf /etc/samba
```

Run "testparm -s" again to make sure it's happy.

Comment: Running testparm gave:
john@JohnPC:~$ testparm -s
Load smb config files from /etc/samba/smb.conf
rlimit_max: increasing rlimit_max (1024) to minimum Windows limit (16384)
Error loading services.
There is no file named /etc/samba/smb.conf

Comment: Do you have a smb.conf at /usr/share/samba/smb.conf? If you do see my edit above.

Comment: Directory /etc/samba is empty: therefore no /usr/share/smb.conf. Could this be due to my 'apt purge samba' followed by 'apt install samba', which was advised by someone on another web site. I have 3 files (smb.conf, gdbcommands and smbusers) in /etc/samba on a Ubuntu 16.04 PC. So would it be a good idea to copy them over to my 18.04 machine?

Comment: Directory /etc/samba is empty: therefore no /usr/share/smb.conf. I did 'sudo cp /usr/share//samba/smb.conf /etc/samba' followed by 'apt upgrade' and things improved but got:
W: APT had planned for dpkg to do more than it reported back (3 vs 7).
   Affected packages: samba:amd64
Is there a fix for this?
BTW I noticed that on another (16.04) PC that there are 2 other files in /etc/samba: gdbcommands & smbusers. Is that significant?

Comment: 'testparm -s' gave:
Load smb config files from /etc/samba/smb.conf
rlimit_max: increasing rlimit_max (1024) to minimum Windows limit (16384)
WARNING: The "syslog" option is deprecated
Processing section "[printers]"
Processing section "[print$]"
Loaded services file OK.
Server role: ROLE_STANDALONE
plus a number of parameter values.

Comment: Just did 'apt upgrade' again and no "Just did 'apt upgrade' again and no W about ". I would like to know how this happened given that I haven't done anything to the directory in question.

Comment: The testparm output looks like it should. AskUbuntu doesn't like a lot of comments so I tried to answer your other questions in your ubuntu forum post. But: I did not understand you last comment. Does this mean everything now works?

Comment: Thanks Morbius1 for your answer & informative help. I would mark your answer as the solution but I don't see any hotspot to click on for this.

Comment: I've never asked a question here but according to: https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers there should be some sort of check mark. Does this make any sense: "To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in."

Answer (score 1):

Same problem over here. The nmbd-logfile complaint about some problems with netbios on ipv6. So I checked smb.conf and at [globals] I found that the interface was bound to 'eth*' but my interface name is 'enp0s31f6'. After changing this smbd and nmbd started both fine. Also my 'apt-get upgrade' problem was gone :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and changed the bound interface in `smb.conf` from `eno0` to `eno1` (my actual interface), but the problem was still there.

Then I realised there was a `smb.conf.ucf-dist` in the same folder `/etc/samba` which had a wrong interface bound `eth0`.

I changed it to `eno1`, saved and then could `apt update` & `upgrade` without having the problem any more ... Look like some config or all of it is taken from this file if it exists in the folder.